# Gerar lista de divisores de um determinado número n

Tags: r

```
guru = function (n){

  if (n>0){
    x = (n%%(1:n) == 0)

    cat(x)
  } 
}
```

Então, eu preciso criar um vetor que contenha todos os divisores de `n`, mas quando eu testo, com algum valor de `n`, ele me diz de forma lógica se tal número na divisão dá resto 0 ou não dá, queria saber como faço para saber quais números e como faço para armazenar tais números num vetor.

```
Ex: guru (3)
TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver esse problema basta usar `which(vetor lógico)`.
Note que fiz duas outras modificações. Incluí o `newline` a terminar o `cat` e agora a função não se limita a printar qualquer coisa, retorna um valor.

```
guru <- function(n){
  if (n > 0){
    x <- which(n%%(1:n) == 0)
    cat(x, "\n")
    x
  }
}

guru(3)        # Número primo
guru(8)        # Número composto
```

No entanto, creio que o seguinte é melhor.

```
guru2 <- function(n) if (n > 0) which(n%%(1:n) == 0)

guru2(3)        # Número primo
guru2(8)        # Número composto
guru2(12)       # Número composto
guru2(33331)    # Número primo
```